# Caliburn.Micro activateitem and Ioc injection of IWindowManager

Tags: caliburn.micro

I'm learning about using Caliburn.Micro as a MVVM framework for a WPF application. In view X I want to show another view Y using `ActivateItem`. In this view Y, when the user clicks a button, I need to show another view Z as a dialog. So I need an instance of `WindowManage` in view Y.

This means that the `WindowManage` will have to be injected into viewmodel of Y, so I can use it to call `windowManager.ShowDialog()` for view Z.
So I was thinking that I should add a constructor into viewmodel of Y which accepts an `IWindowManager` parameter.

```cs
public YViewModel( IWindowManager windowManager) { ... }
```

Can Caliburn.Micro automatically inject the instance of the viewmanager into `YViewModel`? Without the `WindowManage` I would write

```cs
ActivateItem(new YViewModel());
```

but this won't work when I need the `WindowManage`... how am I suppose to write `ActivateItem` when `YViewModel` needs an instance of the `WindowManage`?

Comment: Currently I solved it by removing IWindowManager from the constructor parameters and by putting code in the constructor :
_windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();

Comment: Service Location - bad juju.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro is no IoC container itself. Its built-in bootstrapper has a simple IoC implementation (rather a service locator) which cannot do dependency injection like you want to do with the `IWindowManager` constructor parameter.

Though your solution works it will only do so in the simple cases and it is also considered bad practice to call a service locator from your classes.

There are plenty of good IoC containers around. I would recommend having a look at Unity or Autofac. For both you will find adapted Caliburn.Micro bootstrappers on the internet.

In Autofac for example you would have a line like:

```cs
builder.Register<IWindowManager>(c => new MyWindowManager()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

inside your custom Autofac bootstrapper. Whenever YViewModel gets instantiated through the IoC container the same instance of MyWindowManager would get injected.